# error converting data types when importing excel file into sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

As a SQL beginner, I am trying to import data from Excel to a table in sql server. I imported the data using sql import wizard. Since the wizard always defaut some of my numeric columns into nvarchar and won't allow me to change it in mapping, I planned to import the data into a temp table, then use INSERT with CAST function to transfer the data into the permanent target table. 
When doing the insert, however, I got the error of 'error converting data type nvarchar to numeric'. anyone can tell me why and how to solve the issue? Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO [DatabaseA].[dbo].[mstr_Project]
  ([Project_Start_Year]
  ,[Project_Name]
  ,[Client_Name]
  ,[Client_Revenue_in_Millions]
  ,[Client_Employee_Number])
SELECT [ProjectStartYear]
  ,[ProjectName]
  ,[ClientName]
  ,CAST([ClientRevenuesInMillions] AS NUMERIC)
  ,CAST([EmployeeNo] AS NUMERIC)
FROM [dbo].[temp_ProjectImport]
```

Thanks a million!!

Comment: Look in your excel file for any instances where ClientRevenuesInMillions (or any of the other columns that are failing) contain alphabetical characters. The error is telling you exactly what is wrong, there are values that can't be turned into numbers in those columns.

Comment: My problematic numeric columns are all empty with no values. I guess that's why Excel thinks they are nvarchar based on the column header. How can i make Excel think that they are actually numeric, but just not having values for now?

Answer (score 0):

you could do this `convert(nvarchar(255), @col)`

```
INSERT INTO [DatabaseA].[dbo].[mstr_Project]
      ([Project_Start_Year]
      ,[Project_Name]
      ,[Client_Name]
      ,[Client_Revenue_in_Millions]
      ,[Client_Employee_Number])
    SELECT [ProjectStartYear]
      ,[ProjectName]
      ,[ClientName]
      ,CAST([ClientRevenuesInMillions] AS NUMERIC)
      ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255),[EmployeeNo] ) as new_converted_value
    FROM [dbo].[temp_ProjectImport]
```